# Java - what does 0xXXXc means?

Tags: java, hex

I came acrros this line:

```
int b = (0x001c >> 1)
```

And I don't know what this little `c` next to `0x001` means.
I know that `0x` is for hex but I've never seen this `c` before..

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure it isn't just the hexadecimal digit C?

Comment: yeah you right my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

The `C` is the hexadecimal `C` which is 12(in decimal).

In you case, `0x001C` shifted right by `1`.

In other words `28`(in decimal), shifted by 1 place to right would be `14`(in decimal).

In binary,

`0...00 00011100 >> 00000001`

gives..

`0...00 00001110(in binary)`

Which is: `14`(in decimal) or `E`(in hex)

Answer (score 0):

In base 10, there are ten digits: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9

In base 2, there are only two: 0, 1

In hexadecimal (base 16), there are 16: 0-9 and a, b, c, d, e & f. Sometimes the capital letter is used: both are fine.

So `0x001c`<sub>16</sub> means 0x1<sub>16</sub> x 16<sub>10</sub> + 0xc<sub>16</sub> x 1 = 16<sub>10</sub> + 12<sub>10</sub> = 28<sub>10</sub>

Answer (score 0):

This here

```
int b = (0x001c >> 1)
```

can be analyzed as:

1. **int b**  is declaring a variable of the type integer with the name b, this will be at the same value initialize...
2. **0x001c** is a number but represented in a [hexadecimal format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal)
3. the **>>** is a [shift operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html)

so b is initialized with the result of the operation **0x001c >> 1** soon or later you will discover that this operation is just a division by 2

## summarising:

That line is creating an integer variable initialized with the value 14